# BruteForce to get real url javascript

Tags: javascript, brute-force

Anyone tell me how i can bruteforce to get real url.
for URL Example abc.com/3XXXXXXXX 
X => can be a number or Alpha

i need like

```
const letter = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

to fetch the url like
abc.com/3aaaaaaa1
abc.com/3aaaaaaa2
abc.com/3aaaaaaa3
```

Comment: Make every combination possible from your array of characters and make a `GET` request to each of them. But, as you're bruteforcing, performance is gonna suck.

Comment: You want all possible permutations of `letter` to the power of `unknownSequenceLength`. There are plenty of permutation algorithms out there.

Comment: For what use-case would you want to do something like that? I cannot imagine one

Comment: @NicoVanBelle It could be used to find (presumably) hidden content on sites like pastebin.

Comment: @byxor yes sure I can imagine some that balance the line of decency, that is not my question. If everyone does shit like this, the site's owner would call it a DDOS

Comment: The complexity of brute forcing ~8+ string length permutations can bring your performance down significantly; I would start looking at really efficient permutation algorithms first and then testing on a much smaller URL length for sanity